# Set viewport meta-tag in vue.js application

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For developing and building my project, I use Vue CLI 3.

When building my project, it adds these meta-tags to `index.html` by default.

```
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

However, for mobile I want to add `user-scalable=no` to the `viewport`-tag.

How can I override these meta-Tags?

With [vue-head](https://github.com/ktquez/vue-head) and [vue-meta](https://github.com/declandewet/vue-meta), I had no luck. These plugins only add meta-tags instead of overrideing them.

Comment: Could be wrong, but I believe _Vue_ only adds these once on project creation. If you manually modify your `index.html` file is it overwritten later in the development process?...

Comment: vue cli uses webpack. So you might be able to specify a custom template by providing a HtmlWebpackPlugin in the `vue.config.js` file's `configureWebpack` hook. See: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates

Comment: "However, for mobile I want to add user-scalable=no to the viewport-tag." — That is almost always a terrible idea with accessibility implications.

Comment: Confirming what @War10ck said, you can update `index.html` straight in your editor. Vue won't modify this file, it's only created when you start a new project.

Comment: You can just modify the `index.html` file directly for your meta tags.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[thanksd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2678454/thanksd) brought me to the right answer. Since Vue CLI already has the *html-webpack-plugin*, I did it the official Vue CLI way (https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-plugin).

1 - Added *public/index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

2 - Set meta-tag in *vue.config.js*

```
chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config
        .plugin('html')
        .tap(args => {
            args[0].title = 'MyApp title';
            args[0].meta = {viewport: 'width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no'};

         return args;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with using `vue-meta`.

1. Don't add them statically in your `index.html` file.
2. Add them using `vue-meta`
3. Set the `vmid` property to some unique identifier, that way `vue-meta` will replace the contents of the existing meta tag rather than creating a new one.

Answer (score -1):

> When building my project, it adds these meta-tags to index.html by
>   default.

Yes, but you can modify *index.html* at your will after that.

> How can I override these meta-Tags?

You can either hard code them directly in the classic way in index.html or use the plugins you mentioned.

> With vue-head and vue-meta, I had no luck. These plugins only add
>   meta-tags instead of overrideing them.

That is not a plugin's problem: HTML does not provide a way to override meta tags. It is up to you to set the right meta tags.

Answer (score -1):

If, like me, you are interested in dynamic [Open Graph protocol](https://ogp.me/) meta tags, you'll need to use the more verbose syntax to make sure you add Meta tags with `property` (instead of name) and `content` tags.

I know the original question doesn't specifically ask for these types of tags, but I'm going to share this to hopefully help anyone else who looking and couldn't find an answer to cover a broader type of meta tags.

Here's an example, where you pass in an array of objects, instead of a single object:

```
config.plugin('html').tap(args => {
    args[0].meta = [
        {
            property: 'og:image',
            content: `${environment_url}/images/logos/my_logo.png`,
        },
        {
            property: 'og:image:width',
            content: '1200',
        },
        {
            property: 'og:image:height',
            content: '1200',
        },
    ];
    return args;
});
```

You *can* define multiple meta tags in a single object (when you use the non-Array approach), but you'll lose control of the "property" tag name.

I was able to find this syntax within the examples show on this page:
https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template